# I do not understand answer that proves angle theta

Tags: trigonometry

Given:
The chord AB of circle centre O and radius 10 cm, has a length 18,65 cm and subtends an angle of theta radians at O.

Question:
Show that theta = 2,4

Answer:
(18,65)^2 = 200 - 200 * cos(theta

I do not understand the approach. Why would the RHS be equal to the LHS?

PS: I've just been on holidays for the last three weeks, my maths might be a little rusty at this stage, so please no hate if this question is really easy. :P

Answer (score 1):

Consider triangle $OAB$. Note that it is isosceles, since $OA=OB=10$. We know all three sides, and want to know one of its angles. This requires the use of [Cosine Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_law).

> Consider a triangle $DEF$ where angle $\theta$ is opposite side $EF$. Then we have:
>   $$
> (EF)^2=(DE)^2+(EF)^2-2(DE)(EF)\cos\theta
> $$

Hence, by letting $D=O,E=A,F=B$ we obtain:
$$ \begin{align*}
(AB)^2 &= (OA)^2 + (OB)^2 - 2(OA)(OB)\cos \theta \\
(18.65)^2 &= 10^2 + 10^2 - 2(10)(10)\cos \theta \\
(18.65)^2 &= 100 + 100 - 2(100)\cos \theta \\
(18.65)^2 &= 200 - 200\cos \theta \\
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand that we prove angle theta by comparing the areas. I do not fully understand the RHS, could you expand on all the terms? Is this a formula?

Comment: Have you used Cosine Law before? I suppose it technically does involve comparing areas, although I don't really think about it that way. I've edited in some more details.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used Cosine Law before, I guess this sparked the confusion (or maybe I have, but it's long forgotten :P).